# how to make control update itself (partial update) in asp net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a partial view which is used more than once in a page. On clicking a link on each of these controls I want that control to refresh itself. How can I achieve it most easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose that in your main view you are including the partial multiple times:

```
<div class="container"><% Html.RenderPartial("Foo"); %></div>
<div class="container"><% Html.RenderPartial("Foo"); %></div>
<div class="container"><% Html.RenderPartial("Foo"); %></div>
```

And here's the contents of the partial:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("update", "foo", null, new { @class = "update" })%>
<%: DateTime.Now %>
```

Now all that's left is progressively enhance those anchors:

```
$(function () {
    $('a.update').live('click', function () {
        $(this).closest('div.container').load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: hi darin, thanks for the response. when i try this, in first go it updates partial view successfuly. but on clicking the link second time it doesnt update partial view, instead browser shows only partial view content and the rest of the page is gone. also i realized that on second click script doesnt execute. it seems that  event binding effect somehow gets lost. i tried the script in both partial view and in main view, but it didnt work. do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: i'm a stupid. in the first go i'm changing link's css class. that is why it was happening. now it is working. thanks..